# Android phone under $180 with great specs

Tags: android, smartphones

I'm looking for a great android phone with awesome specs, but in a tight budget of under $180(may go a little over).

Here is a list of things I want it to include:

- compatible with micro SD card
- uses android OS
- a good camera(about 13mp camera) 1080p@30fps  w/ flash and auto-focus
- Camera on both sides
- Resolution: 1080 x 1920 pixels (will go with a lower if price and other specs make up for it)
- multi-touch is a must
- Screen Size: atleast 4.7in.
- Must have atleast 3gb ram
- Rootable (unlocked bootloader would be a bonus)
- compatible with Straight Talk

---

Minor things that I would like, but aren't necessary:

- super-Amoled screen
- I would like a phone that would last at least 6 non-stop use and quick charge time
- An led notification bar

---

This will be phone for over a year, so I need to last a little while. I will be writing programs on it, so I need a medium-big screen. It also needs to have pretty good speed, and can handle some multi-tasking. I would also be recording on the phone as well, while writing programs and/or playing games. I know this is a lot for the price, but I don't have a big budget. I have done some research and here are a few phones I have found: Blu Life One X (2016) and the Moto G (3rd Gen). I really like the Blu Life One X, but there quite a bit of reviews about the screen touch not working and the battery being terrible and wanted to get some input on that. Also found another 1 that i think I might get lenovo k3 note. But what about the xiaomi redmi note 2.

Also, I will also consider buying a used phone off ebay or amazon.

**I have noticed that I can get a used(risking that it doesn't last or work) Galaxy note 3 on ebay for $148-180. I will also give bounty that put's up a good argument on weather I should get one of the new phones mentioned above, the Galaxy Note 3, or another phone used or new of your choice that can compare.**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'll keep this as short and as on point as possible:
Get the [**Samsung Galaxy S4**](http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_s4_cdma-5388.php) because it is a

> great android phone with awesome specs, but in a tight budget of under
>   $180(may go a little over).

Typically $130-180 unlocked second hand, [$150 on a quick amazon search for Straight Talk](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B013IOLDA0). [New for $208](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00S3FEOAG).

Apparently [$150 new at Walmart for **Verizon**.](http://www.walmart.com/ip/Verizon-Samsung-Galaxy-S4-Prepaid-Smartphone/47090196)

It satisfies all of the following:

> Here is a list of things I want it to include:
>
> - compatible with micro SD card
> - uses android OS
> - a good camera(about 13mp camera) 1080p@30fps w/ flash and auto-focus
> - Camera on both sides
> - Resolution: 1080 x 1920 pixels (will go with a lower if price and other specs make up for it)
> - multi-touch is a must
> - Screen Size: about 4.7-5.2 in.
> - At least 2gb of ram
> - Rootable (unlocked bootloader would be a bonus) - *plenty of help available for this popular phone* [e.g. xda developers forums](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2380325)
> - compatible with Straight Talk

and also **has super-amoled screen**.

Obviously hard to say what 6 hours non-stop use is, but according to specs: stand-by up to 350 hrs (3G), talk time up to 11 hrs (3G) and music play up to 69 hrs. It does have a **removable battery** so for an $10-15 extra you can get an official Samsung battery and effectively double the battery life. You're probably better off getting an **official Samsung Adaptive Fast Charger** in a bricks and mortar store.

Don't really understand what you mean by

> An led notification bar

Hope that helps.

---

Addendum (so the comments section doesn't get too lengthy):

With the required spec changes from 2GB RAM to 3GB, no upper limit on screen size and assuming this

> but in a tight budget of under $180(may go a little over).

means ~10% over, so ~$200, it looks like the Samsung Note 3 (obviously 2nd hand) and the [Xiamoi Mi4 (non-LTE, $160)](http://www.gearbest.com/cell-phones/pp_155566.html) are your only candidates.

If you stretch again by $20 you can find the [Xiamoi Note 3](http://www.honorbuy.com/598-xiaomi-redmi-note-3-3gb-ram-32gb-silver.html).

For me personally, if it was taking me a long time to find a Samsung Note 3 that I really liked, I'd stretch out the budget and get the Xiamoi Note 3 to end the wait.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37183/discussion-on-answer-by-rustynuts-android-phone-under-180-with-great-specs).

Answer (score 3):

I find this one fits most of your requirements.

[AT&T GoPhone - ZTE Zmax 2 4G with 16GB Memory No-Contract Cell Phone - Black ($99.99 + free shipping @ best buy)](http://www.bestbuy.com/site/at-t-gophone-zte-zmax-2-4g-with-16gb-memory-no-contract-cell-phone-black/4421800.p?id=1219745390060&skuId=4421800)

### 1.2GHz processor with 2GB of RAM

(Snapdragon 410, 4 x A53 @ 1.2 GHz)

Delivers outstanding overall performance for opening and running applications, flipping through menus, running home screens and more.

### Android 5.1 Lollipop OS

New colors and typography, new ways to control when and how you receive messages, and new security features, including Android Smart Lock, which secures your phone by pairing it with a trusted smartwatch or other device.

### 5.5" touch-screen display

(720p LCD)

Large screen makes it easy to navigate pages and watch videos.

### 8.0MP rear-facing camera

Snap photos of memorable moments while you're on the go. Also includes a 2.0MP front-facing camera for video chatting and taking selfies.

### 16GB internal memory

Offers plenty of storage space for music, photos, contacts and more.

### Use your smartphone as a mobile hotspot

Share your 4G data connection with other compatible wireless devices

### SD card

microSD, up to 64 GB

[More specs at GSMArena](http://www.gsmarena.com/zte_zmax_2-7572.php)

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe there are any phones with your specifications under $199. Here is my recommendation:

The [Honor 5X](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B019O8YWR0) - $199

- Android 5.1
- Dual camera (13MP back)
- 2GB RAM
- Compatible with both AT&T and T-Mobile sim cards (This also means StraightTalk)
- Full 1080p HD 5.5" multitouch screen
- Easily [rootable](http://forum.xda-developers.com/honor-5x/development/root-kiw-l24-usa-kiwi-t3305190) (unlockable bootloader)
- MicroSD card slot
- 16GB internal storage

Answer (score 1):

English is not my native language so please be patient.

Your requeriments doesn't go with your budget, so you'll have to drop some requeriments, especially for non chinese brands.

I would recomend the [Xiaomi RedMi 2Pro](http://www.gsmarena.com/xiaomi_redmi_2_pro-7710.php) ($147 US):

- Compatible with micro SD card (Yes)
- Uses android OS (Yes 4.4 upgradable to 5.1)
- A good camera(Yes, but 8MP) 1080p@30fps (Yes) w/flash and auto-focus (rear Camera only)
- Camera on both sides. (Yes 8MP and 2MP)
- Resolution: 1080 x 1920 pixels (No,  720 x 1280 pixels ~312 ppi pixel density)
- Multi-touch is a must. (Yes)
- Screen Size: atleast 4.7in. (Yes)
- Must have atleast 3GB RAM (No, 2GB)
- Rootable (unlocked bootloader would be a bonus) (Yes, not sure about the bootloader)
- Compatible with Straight Talk (Not sure, but I think this depends more of the country than the phone)
- 4G LTE (Bonus)
- Multicolor Notification Led (Bonus)
- Dual SIM (Bonus)
- First 30% Quick Charge (Bonus)

But more accurate to your needs is the [Xiaomi RedMi Note 3 Pro](http://www.gsmarena.com/xiaomi_redmi_note_3-7863.php) ($210 US). This satisfies all your needs and bring you **awesome bonuses**:

- Compatible with micro SD card (Yes)
- Uses android OS (Yes, 5.1)
- A good camera(Yes) 1080p@30fps (Yes) w/flash and auto-focus (Both Sides)
- Camera on both sides. (Yes 16MP and 5MP)
- Resolution: 1080 x 1920 pixels (Yes,~403 ppi pixel density)
- Multi-touch is a must. (Yes)
- Screen Size: atleast 4.7in. (Yes, 5.5)
- Must have atleast 3GB RAM (Yes, **Pro Model** come with 3GB)
- Rootable (unlocked bootloader would be a bonus) (Yes, not sure about the bootloader)
- Compatible with Straight Talk (Not sure, but I think this depends more of the country than the phone)
- Fingerprint (Bonus)
- 4G LTE (Bonus)
- Multicolor Notification Led (Bonus)
- Dual SIM (Bonus)
- Quick Charge (Bonus)