# Bluetooth MP3 Player with m3u playlist support?

Tags: wireless, bluetooth, mp3-player, sd-card

I'm looking for a bluetooth mp3 player with playlists support. Playlists in preferably editable text format (m3u,pls,xml), and not in binary non-editable format. 
I've been searching since quite some time, and found onn, fiio, sony, philips and apple to be providing bluetooth mp3 players, although none seemed to fit in `$250 USD + playlists` options...

I bought a ruizu mp3 player + 64gb sd/tf card, and it didn't turn out to be what I expected. Had bluetooth, but no playlists support for bluetooth. I accidentally broke it, and would buy it again if it had playlists support!

Anyways, please could anyone here suggest a bluetooth mp3 player with playlists within $250 USD price range? Thanks!

**EDIT:**
Answer to the comment by **LiveWireBT**:

Can you please shine some more light on what your requirements for a "Bluetooth MP3 Player" are?

- *Do smartphones qualify?* 
  `[yes! Even regular phones with play/pause buttons + playlists support in bluetooth]`
- *Which size?* 
  `[not very big or heavy, similar to an ipod, although not very expensive.]`
- *Battery life?* 
  `[85+ Hours]`
- *Bluetooth version?* 
  `[2.1+ EDR]`
- *How much storage (SDHC/SDXC)?* 
  `[expandable via SD/TF card to 64 gb.]`
- *Should it play audio in high quality stereo (A2DP) to Bluetooth headphones and speakers?* 
  `[yes! Loud Volume + Quality of sound]`
- *Should it transfer files over Bluetooth (I can think of better ways)?* 
  `[nope, file transfer not required.]`
- *Just support for MP3, no AAC, FLAC, Vorbis, Opus?* 
  `[only mp3, and (if possible) m4a.]`
- *Hi-Res Audio?* 
  `[I don't understand what High Res Audio might mean... I have (128-320kbps + 44100 Hz) mp3 files.]`
- *Podcasts?* 
  `[nope]`
- *Is a touch screen okay or too big?* 
  `[touch screen is fine!]`
- *A certain resolution if you eventually want to play movies?* 
  `[nope]`

Answer (score 1):

If you can spend up to 250 USD and if it doesn't have to be very tiny then I would recommend to look for a smartphone¹. Several apps exist, among them **VLC for Android**, iOS and Windows Phone. I just tried it on Android which works fine with m3u playlists (I never bothered to try until now and VLC on my Windows Phone somehow doesn't read the same file, even if I replace the path delimiters).

You can usually get good midrange smartphones in the 200 USD/€ price tier (+ the price for a storage card) with Bluetooth 4.0, more comfortable file sync through apps like Syncthing or ownCloud and HD movie playback capability. Here are some related questions that have already been asked:

- [Android phone under $180 with great specs](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/2199/1329)
- [Smartphones under $100 for Android Development](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/48/1329)

Edit: In case you're wondering, you can get decent a2dp in-ears from [QCY](http://www.qcymall.com/) for under 20 USD and decent fit (I forced Comply foam tips on mine, even though Comply doesn't want support them).

---

1. You don't have to use it as a phone that spies on you if you don't want to.